# How to create array of objects in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have few input fields like "Title" "firstname" "lastname" and "date" whose data I'm storing in an Object but I want to create an array of object for this data, so that every time I click submit button a new object should be pushed in the array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Basic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form>
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input ng-model="user.title">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input ng-model="user.first_name">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input ng-model="user.last_name">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Enter date</label>
            <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate"></md-datepicker>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-warn" ng-click="saveData()">Submit</md-button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS file:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']).controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {}
    var userArr = [];

    $scope.saveData = function () {
        console.log("user", $scope.user)
        userArr.push(user);
        console.log(userArr);
    }
})
```

Comment: `userArr.push($scope.user);` you should do like this...

Comment: @McRist thank you.. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

You missed `$scope` from user.

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']).controller('myCtrl', 
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.user = {}
        var userArr = [];

        $scope.saveData = function () {
            console.log("user", $scope.user)
            userArr.push($scope.user)
            console.log(userArr);
        }
    })
```